# Disabling a button in and turning it to grey

Tags: swift, button, conditional-statements

I got a button that opens a new view once pressed.

[the button is called " cálculo "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Cul.png)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let secondViewController:ContasView = segue.
destinationViewController as! ContasView
```

I don't want it to be enable to be pressed until a label value is not nil. I usually see this kind of button as a grey text button.
So, two questions:
 1. How to disable it be this condition?
 2. As soon as it's disabled, how to turn into a grey text button?

Answer (score 0):

Start listening:

```
textField1.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
textField2.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
textField3.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Check values:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    button.enabled = !textField1.text.isEmpty && !textField2.text.isEmpty && !textField3.text.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false
    button.setTitle("ButtonTextHere", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)
    view.addSubview(button)
```

Somewhere in your code, whenever your label changes, you can just do

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = true
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
```